# Android: Enable hardware acceleration

Tags: android, hardware-acceleration

I want my animations in android 4.0 is very slow and lacks. So I want to enable hardware acceleration and have tried to do what [this](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/graphics/hardware-accel.html) page says but with no luck.

You can see my manifest here:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<manifest android:versionCode="1" android:versionName="1.0"
    package="com.jws.battleship" xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="8" android:targetSdkVersion="15"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH_ADMIN"/>
    <application 
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name" 
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Black.NoTitleBar"
        android:hardwareAccelerated="true">
        <activity 
            android:label="@string/app_name" 
            android:name=".HomeActivity"
            android:hardwareAccelerated="true">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity android:name=".UserPreferences"/>
        <activity android:name=".BattleActivity" android:screenOrientation="landscape"/>
        <activity android:name=".HighScoreActivity"/>
        <activity android:name=".StoreActivity"/>
        <activity android:name=".JoinBattle"/>
        <activity android:name=".CreateBattleActivity"/>
        <activity android:name=".FriendList"/>
        <activity android:name=".FriendListActivity"/>
        <activity android:name=".SelectNetworkActivity"/>
        <activity android:name=".BluetoothDevicesListActivity"/>
        <activity android:name=".NetworkFactoryActivity"/>
    </application>
</manifest>
```

I then test if it has enabled hardware acceleration in onCreate() like this:

```
ListView list = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.home_list_active_games);
Boolean test = list.isHardwareAccelerated();
```

But it always returns false!? Do I need to add some kind of permission or what is wrong here?

BR

Answer (score 5):

The above code looks ok. The same problem is posted at  [HoneyComb isHardwareAccelerated() always returns false](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/android-developers/vAH0HAZg0uU%5B1-25%5D). Yet
[Android 3.0 Hardware Acceleration](http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2011/03/android-30-hardware-acceleration.html) writes

> If you need more fine-grained control, you can enable hardware
>   acceleration for a given window at runtime:

```
    getWindow().setFlags(
    WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_HARDWARE_ACCELERATED,
    WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_HARDWARE_ACCELERATED);
```

Answer (score 1):

Change this to

```
<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="11" android:targetSdkVersion="15"/>
```

Using hardware acceleration requires minSdkVersion 11 or higher.